# Populating a single comboBox with two columns from a databse using Entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework, combobox, linq-to-entities

So, I'm pretty much trying to do what's described in the title. I have a table called Customers and two columns in them called FirstName and LastName and want to display both of those in a combo box. I've tried a few different things, but none seemed to have an effect as the combo box was empty regardless of what I've tried, I've looked through people with similar problems on here too but none of the suggested solutions seem to work for me.

This is how it currently looks like

```
        public void FillComboBox()
    {
        using (CustomerDBEntities c = new CustomerDBEntities())
        {
            comboBox1.DataSource = c.customerdata;
            comboBox1.ValueMember = "PKCustomer";
            comboBox1.DisplayMember = "FirstName"+"LastName";
            comboBox1.Invalidate();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you project the FirstName, LastName in the way you want.

```
var dataSource = c.customerdata.Select(c=> new { string.Format($"{c.FirstName} {c.LastName}") }).ToList();
comboBox1.DataSource = dataSource ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at the [ToString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.tostring(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

If you override the ToString of your CustomerDbEntities.customerdata-object with something like

```
return FirstName + " " + LastName;
```

you should be good even without setting the `DisplayMember` property of your `comboBox`